# Create common component with Swagger annotations

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I am using swagger-annotation for my spring-boot project.

I would like to return a common response code contract for each resource of my controller.

In the doc : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/annotations#apiresponses-apiresponse
they talk about @ApiResponses but I cannot put the annotation at the class level.

Here is what I did:

```
@Api(value = "Title",
    description = "What this controller is about"
)
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad stuff from the client"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Item not found") }
    )
public class FooBarController {

      ...

}
```

But the problem is that `400 - Bad stuff from the client` and `404 - Item not found` are never shown in the generated doc.

In the official doc of swagger I have seen this section: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/#reuse

Question: How can I create a kind of "reusable component" with java annotations ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can do this at the Docket level.

```
.useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
        .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET,
            newArrayList(new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                .code(400)
                .message("Bad stuff from the client")
                .build()))
```

https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot

Update:

If you want to go the annotation route, you can create your own and place it on your controller.

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad stuff from the client"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Item not found") }
    )
public @interface GlobalApiReponses {
}
```

Then use it..

```
@Api(value = "Title",
    description = "What this controller is about"
)
@GlobalApiReponses
public class FooBarController
```

A combination of approaches might be a good option as well.

The @Target(ElementType.TYPE) means you can apply this at the class level. You can do the same for methods by using the ElemenType.METHOD.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. And that is working. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: @HermannSteidel Any tips for how to create a custom annotation for Swagger annotations that don't have the TYPE target?  Such as `ApiModelProperty`